# Transition in Carousel from React-bootstrap not smooth

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

Hey StackOverflow coders,

I'm building out my portfolio from scratch in React and about to deploy it but there is a glitch with the transition of slides in the carousel unfortunately. I've tried everything from changing the width and height of the photos. Here is a video of what's happening.
[Gif of carousel glitch](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsTLbKRukIANh6Ba6xf0V6k1-QPSzA?e=Qikphd)

Next, here is the code in the component.

```
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";
import Slide1 from "../../assets/images/IMG_0261.jpeg";
import Slide2 from "../../assets/images/IMG_0620 (1).jpeg";
import Slide3 from "../../assets/images/IMG_0043.jpeg";
import ScrollDown from "../Scroll-down/scrollDown.component";

const MyCarousel = () => {
  return (
    <div id="home">
      <Carousel controls={false} indicators interval={2500} pause={false}>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            id="slide1"
            className="d-block w-100 "
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
            src={Slide1}
            alt="First slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100 "
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
            src={Slide2}
            alt="Second slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100 "
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
            src={Slide3}
            alt="Third slide"
          />
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
      {/* <div className="overlay"></div> */}
      <ScrollDown />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyCarousel;
```

I've tried everything and it's still glitching. Any suggestions would suffice!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please install [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap?activeTab=versions) version 2. This glitch has been solved in version 2. Just change the package.json as the given code snippet

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.2"
},
```

Then run `npm install`
I hope this fixes your problem.